# MessageDialog from Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-8, windows-runtime, messagedialog

I'm using a Scheduled Task under Windows 8 to trigger a simple .cmd file which contains a series of steps, some of which trigger an external Powershell script.

I want to use the [MessageDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208674) features of Windows 8 to display a model message.

**Is it possible to do this via Powershell? Or another simple script?**

Answer (score 1):

It *is* technically possible to call WinRT APIs from desktop targeted applications (of which powershell is one.)

Take a look here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx

There's still some legwork to do on your behalf, but that should help you figure out the approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be that trivial, the dialog is supported on Windows Store apps only. That said you can use Windows forms to display messages, have you tried it?

Comment: I've noticed that classic SHUTDOWN.EXE Windows application triggers a message using the MessageDialog() modal style, which made me think it's possible outside of a Windows Store app.

Comment: Do display a MessageDialog() style message, like this: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/image_thumb_2F8B115C.png from the command line/PowerShell

Comment: I don't think you can since it is supported only for metro style apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Your message");
```

Check out options for Show() at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox.show?view=windowsdesktop-8.0 if you need something more elaborate.